# Why am I getting my confirmation popup before validation completes?

Tags: javascript, validation, popup, submit

I have a form, my goal is to have a popup window to let the user know their request has been submitted successfully and after the popup window is closed, the page is refreshed (using a header) this works fine except that I get the popup even before all of the data has been validated. I'm using this function.

```
function myFunction(){alert("Your Request Has Been Submitted");}
```

with my submit button

```
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
```

Where do I need to put this function so that the confirmation only popups after all the data has been validated? Do I need an IF statement somewhere?

Comment: You need AJAX. Check MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX

Comment: Do I really need it? Or is that just a suggestion? If at all possible I'd love to stick with straight php and minimal js

Comment: Well you could write the script tag from the server after everything is done, that's the other solution, although not ideal... The click event will happen before sending a request to the server.

Comment: What type of validation are you doing?  Why don't you just display the message on the next page since you're refreshing anyway?

Comment: The goal is for the user to make a submission, have the confirmation popup (inside the popup is an AI ticket number), then the page refreshed, I'd rather not load another page as the user will immediately be coming right back to make another submission. All the client validation is done with js.

Comment: Why don't you use `<form onsubmit="myFunction()">`? myFunction could do the validation and show a popup if everything went fine.

Comment: Yep that will be expected behaviour as the page send out the post request. The alert statement is just ignored. What you can do is add a reference to the url (on return look for the parameter on the URL and pop up the window) or inject js in the server response of the page.

Comment: I've added both functions but I'm still getting the same results, I can open the page, immediately click submit, and I get the confirmation before any validation has occured.

Comment: can you show us a fiddle then?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DrewG85/nQuTQ/ Sorry I'm new to fiddle, I know its not setup correctly, as in I don't know how to get it to run??? Also I don't have the AI ticket ID setup yet in my confirmation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out and it was so amazingly simply!!! My skills are still fairly lacking and I guess as a beginner its easy to unnecessarily complicate things!!!

```
function validateForm(formElement) { 
    var valid = true;
    if (blah blah blah blah)...
    if (blah blah blah blah)...
    if (valid) {
    alert("After all this validation now we can have this sweet confirmation alert!!!")
    }
    return valid;
```

My next step is to enter an auto increment value from the db into the alert, thanks again everyone!!